# How to add a placeholder to an exposed date filter form field?

Tags: views, datetime

This is the structure of a date field in my exposed form:

```
<input id="edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init" type="text" maxlength="200" size="20" value="" name="date_filter[value][date]">
```

I added this code under

```
function bartik_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

to add place holder.

```
$form['date_filter']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But place holder is not coming. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can try under Expose this filter to user checkbox there is one label and description field add (YYYY-MM-DD) will display on expose form to select date format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery may be a solution.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 jQuery('#edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0').attr("placeholder", "placeholder to show");
});
```